# Change element's CSS for 5 seconds, but persist if next event is still within 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm building an app with beacons. Whenever an event is fired I want to change the background color to red for 5 seconds, then back to blue after the 5 seconds is up. Without complication this is very easy I just use a $timeout and voila.

My problem is that if the event if fired again **within** that same 5 seconds, I want to extend the length that the background is red to be 5 seconds from then.

My current code sort of does the job but keeps flickering whenever the original 5 seconds is up.

```
            $('#reportingLoopPage').removeClass('positive-bg');
            $('#reportingLoopPage').addClass('assertive-bg');

            $timeout(function () {
                $('#reportingLoopPage').removeClass('assertive-bg');
                $('#reportingLoopPage').addClass('positive-bg');
            }, 5000);
```

How can I persist a change for a duration of 5 seconds, resetting that duration whenever the event is fired again?

I'm happy to use any combo of JS, Angular, and JQuery

Comment: Call `$timeout.cancel(promise)` and then immediately set a new `$timeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that if the event if fired again within that same 5 seconds, I want to extend the length that the background is red to be 5 seconds from then.

You could use `$timeout.cancel(promiseVariable)` to cancel the current timer and create a new one.

```
var promise;

//More code...

$('#reportingLoopPage').removeClass('positive-bg');
$('#reportingLoopPage').addClass('assertive-bg');

$timeout.cancel(promise);

promise = $timeout(function () {
    $('#reportingLoopPage').removeClass('assertive-bg');
    $('#reportingLoopPage').addClass('positive-bg');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use nested timeouts.

```
$timeout(function () {
    $('#reportingLoopPage').removeClass('assertive-bg');
    $timeout(function () {
        $('#reportingLoopPage').addClass('positive-bg');
    }, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.delay()` also possible.

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

```
$('#reportingLoopPage').delay(5000).removeClass('assertive-bg');
$('#reportingLoopPage').delay(10000).addClass('positive-bg');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTimeout;

function myFunction()
{
    $('#reportingLoopPage').removeClass('positive-bg');
    $('#reportingLoopPage').addClass('assertive-bg');

    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#reportingLoopPage').removeClass('assertive-bg');
            $('#reportingLoopPage').addClass('positive-bg');
        }, 5000);
}
```